# Sharepoint custom user and document library specific properties

Tags: sharepoint, properties, profiler

Is there a standard way to associate custom properties with a user? I need to store the number of items per page a user selected in a grid of a document library separately for each user and document library.

**Edit:**

Sorry about this vagueness, I wanted to do it *programmatically*. It seems like I've found the solution, it is [UserProfileManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.aspx) class, though I'm now looking into whether there is a limitation on the number of properties you can save this way for a user, because the easiest way of saving page sizes on per user+document library basis seems to be using GUIDs of Views as property names and numbers of pages as values. Though I don't know if it is more efficient or not, depends on how sharepoint stores these properties.

Answer (score 1):

No, you would need to create custom code to store the data.

Given the potential amount of data created, it may be wise to store it in a separate database.

This would give greater flexibility in the way the data can be manipulated and retrieved.

Comment: I have to agree with Nat, it would be quite complicating if you save it on the same database, the best practice would be to save it on a separate database.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. Are you looking to do any custom code? You could do this many ways so it is difficult without knowing more of what you want.

Using custom code you could set up a workflow or event handler to respond to item events and record the information and store it using the User's Profile or as an SPPersistedObject.

If you want a less developer centric way to do it you can use auditing and simply do reporting on your audit results.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a list to store the selection data, then use events/AJAX on the document list to push tick/untick items into the selection list (store user, library and document as a minimum.

If you don't want a separate list, you could create a field in your document library that stores which users have a given document tagged... You'll still need some kind of event/AJAX to update the list when a user ticks/unticks the box.  Crude :)